# How to restrict unwanted routes in angular cli?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have set up the routing modules in my angular 8 application using lazy loading. I have set up multiple routing modules. In my authentication routing module, I set a path for `/auth/login`. However `/login` also redirects to that same component. How can I restrict this routing?

App-routing.module

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "auth",
    loadChildren: "./authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule"
  },
  {
    path: "user",
    loadChildren: "./user/user.module#UserModule"
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "auth/login"
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Authentication-routing.module

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "login",
    component: LoginPageComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

I expected to load the login component only when I go to the `/auth/login` route, but it's also loading when I go to the `/login` route without redirecting.

Here is the sample project on stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qor5kr

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz of this issue??

Comment: You mean to say `localhost:4200/login` and `localhost:4200/auth/login` navigativing to same and you need to restrict `localhost:4200/login`?

Comment: the answer from @Sergey Mell is correct. All your 404 are redirecting to `auth/login`. You  need to update that if want to restrict routes

Comment: @SmokeyDawson, I added the stackblitz link to the question.

Comment: @Chaitanya, yes. however there are multiple components in that module. so the problem is not only about the login path.

Comment: @RavinduSachintha, I've figured out what's the issue. See the update for my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this happens because you redirect “all other routes” `(path: ‘**’)` to `auth/login`. So the problem is not exactly in `/login` route.

If you want to restrict the `/login` path only - create separate component for it.

Also, you can put a [Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) on `path: **` route and implement appropriate redirects. Smth like this:

```
// routes
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "auth/login",
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }

// Guard
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    if (state.url === '/login') {
        // Handle redirect here
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After examine the [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qor5kr) I've figured out what's the problem. You have included lazy loaded `AuthenticationModule` directly into `AppModule` module. That caused the artifacts. You should remove it

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    // AuthenticationModule, <= It's lazy loaded and should not be included
    AppRoutingModule
    ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

See the corrected example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-problem-stackoverflow?file=src/app/app.module.ts).

Comment: Why do I get a negative rating? What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: im not the downvoter but since angular routing use a first-match wins, if it found `auth` route first, then it not going into `"**"` route

Comment: Yeah, but the problem in `/login` route. Angular router doesn't find any appropriate, gets till `**` and then is being redirected to `/auth/login`. So, I've proposed two solutions about how to avoid this

Comment: @SergeyMell there are some several components inside the authentication module. This same problem is happened to all that. I tried "guards" solution as your answer. However it's not even trigger, when go to a different url, but redirect as usual. I tried same guard in the "auth" path and it's trigger and  work well. The problem isn't solved yet.

Comment: Please, provide a https://stackblitz.com example then so I could reproduce your problem and help you more effectively.

Comment: @RavinduSachintha, stackblitz helped. The problem was in your modules, not routings. See the update for my answer

Comment: The updated solution is solved my problem. Thank you @SergeyMell.